# Matrices and the Dot Product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Prove that real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $Ax \cdot Ay=x \cdot y$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $| Ax| = |x|$.

$\textbf{My Attempt}$

Write $Ax \cdot Ay= A^2 ( x \cdot y)$. Then $A^2 = I$, so $A$ is maybe orthogonal. I am not sure. Furthermore, I can't really use this to prove the statement.

Also, I am not sure if the very first step is correct. I know nothing of how matrices behave with inner products.

Comment: You can't do $A^2 (x \cdot y)$ because $x \cdot y$ is a number, not   a vector. However, you can do $A x \cdot A y = (A^T A x) \cdot y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote an $n \times n$ real matrix.

> **Definitions.** Call $A$ *dot-product preserving* iff $x \cdot y = Ax \cdot Ay$ for all relevant vectors $x$ and $y$. On the other hand, let
>   us call $A$ *length-preserving* iff $|x| = |Ax|$ for all relevant
>   vectors $x$.

Now suppose $A$ is dot-product preserving. Let $x$ be fixed-but-arbitrary. Then $x \cdot x = Ax \cdot Ax$. Hence $|x|^2 = |Ax|^2$. So $|x|=|Ax|.$

On the other hand, suppose $A$ is length-preserving. Let $x$ and $y$ be fixed-but-arbitrary. Using the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) twice, we have

$$x \cdot y = \frac{1}{4}\left(|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2\right)$$

$$Ax \cdot Ay = \frac{1}{4}\left(|Ax+Ay|^2-|Ax-Ay|^2\right)$$

But since $A$ is length-preserving, we have that the two LHS's are equal (make sure you can show this, it should only take a few steps). Hence so too are the RHS's.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: (1) $Ax\cdot Ax=|Ax|^2$;

(2) One has
$$
Ax\cdot Ay=\frac14 (A(x+y)\cdot A(x+y)-A(x-y)\cdot A(x-y)).
$$